# brew python versus non-brew ipython

Tags: python, macos, ipython, homebrew

I installed python via brew, and made it my default python. If I run `which python`, I obtain `/usr/local/bin/python`. Also pip is installed via brew, `which pip` returns `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

I do not remember how I installed ipython, but I didn't do it via brew, since when I type `which ipython`, I obtain `/opt/local/bin/ipython`. Is it the OS X version of ipython?

I installed all libraries on this version of ipython, for example I have matplotlib on ipython but not on python. I do not want to re-install everything again on the brew python, rather continue to install libraries on this version of ipython. How can I install new libraries there? For example, Python Image Library, or libjpeg?

If possible, I would like an exhaustive answer so to understand my problem, and not just a quick fix tip.

Comment: Why did you install pip with brew? The python brew installation already has pip. And you install ipython via pip as well, not brew...

Comment: Try Anaconda Python: https://www.continuum.io/downloads.  You'll avoid all of the rabbit holes associated with a Brew Python.  It will install IPython, matplotlib, etc. and make them them default.  After you can either use conda install or pip install to install new packages like the Python Image Library.  conda install sometimes has user defined installation routines that are machine specific (ie for Mac or Linux) to replace what you might find in Brew.  For me, which Python/IPython leads to the same path: /home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin (plus /python or /ipython).

Answer (score 1):

> I installed `python` via `brew`, and made it my default python. If I run `which python`, I obtain `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Okay, good so far.

> Also `pip` is installed via `brew`, which pip returns `/usr/local/bin/pip`.

Actually, not quite `brew install python` would have installed `pip` because even doing `brew search pip` comes up with this warning.

```
If you meant "pip" precisely:

Homebrew provides pip via: `brew install python`. However you will then
have two Pythons installed on your Mac, so alternatively you can install
pip via the instructions at:
  https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installing/
```

So, Python came with pip, not `brew install`

> when I type `which ipython`, I obtain `/opt/local/bin/ipython`. Is it the OSX version of ipython?

There is no "OSX version of ipython"...

> I installed all libraries on this version of ipython, for example I have `matplotlib` on ipython but not on python.

You actually did install them to your brew installed Python. IPython is not a new installation of Python.

You can even start a `python` interpreter from the terminal and `import matplotlib` to check this

> I do not want to re-install everything again on the brew python

What exactly needs re-installed? It's already installed into the brew python

Comment: Hi thank you! So I figured out that ipython is probably installed via macport, so this is why it is under opt/local/bin. I did open python from terminal, that's how I checked that I don't have matplotlib (for example)

Comment: I see... Using my brew installation, when I do `pip install ipython`, it goes to `/usr/local/bin/ipython`

Comment: so how can I switch to the brew ipython? currently which ipython returns the other one

Comment: Again, you are confusing `brew` with `pip`. You have to uninstall the other ipython however you installed it. If you used macports, then use that. If you can't figure out how, then simple see what `pip install ipython` does.

Comment: yes I meant the pip ipython, sorry. So I uninstalled macport, a bit drastic but it works, now I am on pip ipython. Now I need to re-install everything via pip...

Comment: If you had kept the `pip` version from macports, then you could have frozen the packages, as the other answer mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer all your packages you can use pip to freeze all of your packages installed in ipython and then install them all easily from the file that you put them in.

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

then to install them from the file `pip install -r requirements.txt`

I'm not entirely sure if I understood what you're asking so if this isn't what you want to do please tell me.

Comment: thank you for your answer. The first question I have is: if I run which ipython, I obtain /opt/local/bin/ipython. Is it the OSX version of ipython? How could I switch to the brew version, under /usr/local/bin/?

Comment: @user2343952 As far as I know, the OSX path of python is `/usr/local/bin/python`. Unfortunately i've never been this situation, nor have I ever used iPython.

Comment: yes it is, but not for ipython it seems. If I run type -a ipython, I obtain /opt/local/bin/ipython and /usr/local/bin/ipython (the brew version)

Comment: ok, I understand that I installed ipython via macport, so this is why it is under opt/local/bin. I would like to switch to ipython installed via pip, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I solved by uninstalling macport (and so the ipython I was using, which was under /opt/local/bin) and installing ipython via pip. Then I re-install what I needed (e.g. jupyter) via pip.